# Replace all <img> tags with one word in XML file

Tags: python, html, regex, xml, python-2.7

I have XML file, that consits of many twit with html tags in them. 
Among all the other tasks, I need to replace all  tags with a word @emoji
I have written the following code:

```
for word in re.findall(r"&lt;img[\w\W]+?/&gt;",line):
    print word
    line = line.replace(word,'@emoji')
```

It is perfectly working for the line. 
However, when I try to do it in the loop for the whole file, it is not going inside this loop. Here is the code:

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET #xml lib
filename = 'da0d0e3527b931bb0bc6f5435003ea2a.xml'
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
twits = []
for child in root:
   for grandchild in child:
        twits.append(grandchild.text)
for line in twits:
    for word in re.findall(r"&lt;img[\w\W]+?&gt;",line):
        line = line.replace(word,'@img')
    print line
```

I was also trying to do the same with html parser, but I can't turn tag to string:

```
imgs = soup.find_all('img')
for img in imgs:
    print img
    emo = str(img)
    twit.replace(emo,'@emoji')
```

The xml file it very big to publish it completly, but it looks like this:

```
<author>
    <documents>
        <document id="396228853267714048" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396228853267714048">Sooooo many slutty cats knocking around last night</document>
        <document id="396229373554360320" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396229373554360320">&lt;a href="/AndyLee666" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" data-mentioned-user-id="259958055" &gt;&lt;s&gt;@&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;AndyLee666&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; yep, eye hurts but doesn&amp;#39;t look bad ha ha</document>
        <document id="396326071467270144" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396326071467270144">Time to start saving for a Skyline</document>
        <document id="396326916372054016" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396326916372054016">@LaurenWeale where were your halo and wings then?</document>
        <document id="396327202260017152" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396327202260017152">@LaurenWeale I didn&amp;#39;t see them, and besides, it&amp;#39;s not a scary costume</document>
        <document id="396327842252075008" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396327842252075008">@LaurenWeale ahh beat me to it &lt;img class="Emoji Emoji--forText" src="https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f609.png" draggable="false" alt="&#128521;" title="Winking face" aria-label="Emoji: Winking face"&gt;</document>
        <document id="396328213074677763" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396328213074677763">The best chair ever! &lt;a href="/hashtag/halloween?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" &gt;&lt;s&gt;#&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;halloween&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="/hashtag/Throne?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" &gt;&lt;s&gt;#&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;Throne&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="/hashtag/Devil?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" &gt;&lt;s&gt;#&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;Devil&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="/hashtag/anyforty?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" &gt;&lt;s&gt;#&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;anyforty&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="/hashtag/wasted?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" &gt;&lt;s&gt;#&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;wasted&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="/hashtag/king?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" &gt;&lt;s&gt;#&lt;/s&gt;&lt;b&gt;king&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://somelink" rel="nofollow noopener" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://instagram.com/p/gLi_B9EfOp/" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://instagram.com/p/gLi_B9EfOp/" &gt;&lt;span class="tco-ellipsis"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="invisible"&gt;http://&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="js-display-url"&gt;instagram.com/p/gLi_B9EfOp/&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="invisible"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="tco-ellipsis"&gt;&lt;span class="invisible"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</document>
        <document id="396328831285735424" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396328831285735424">@LaurenWeale sorry, that was mean</document>
        <document id="396337843909713920" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396337843909713920">@LaurenWeale :( don&amp;#39;t be like that</document>
        <document id="396342701568040960" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396342701568040960">@LaurenWeale be like that then &lt;img class="Emoji Emoji--forText" src="https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f624.png" draggable="false" alt="&#128548;" title="Face with look of triumph" aria-label="Emoji: Face with look of triumph"&gt;</document>
        <document id="396345875360129024" url="https://twitter.com/ReissSudden/status/396345875360129024">Been a pure lazy day today &lt;img class="Emoji Emoji--forText" src="https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f44c.png" draggable="false" alt="&#128076;" title="Ok hand sign" aria-label="Emoji: Ok hand sign"&gt;</document>
    </documents>
</author>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `re.sub(pattern, '@emoji', line)` yet? That would make the loop obsolete.

Comment: @Boldewyn just tried, still not working :(

Comment: Why not just use `sed` ?

Comment: @Ôrel Unfortunately, I have no idea about sed. How can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before parsing the file you can `read` it and can do a `re.sub` upon the data to replace **img** with **@emoji** and then parse it using `ET.fromstring`. you can achieve this like

```
from re import sub
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET #xml lib
data = 'da0d0e3527b931bb0bc6f5435003ea2a.xml'
data = re.sub(r"&lt;img[\w\W]","&lt;@emoji",open(data).read())
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
```

now data will contain `&lt;@emoji` in all places of `&lt;img`. now you can parse the resulting data as per your wish.